# How to tell if my Windows 7 copy is not modified?

Tags: windows, backdoor

I lost my windows cd I downloaded a copy from the internet. The guy who shared it said it's original without any modifications. However I get weird actions like I can't use mouse clicks or I can't type a letter on the keyboard, windows get closed. So how can I tell if there's a backdoor or mot?

Answer (score 1):

If you bought an original copy of Windows and lost the CD you should be able to contact Microsoft with your installation code and ask for a replacement.

Don't download an illegal copy of a software from the Internet -- you're looking for trouble. It might very likely be infected with trojans, viruses, or any other kind of malware. Sure, you could run an AV on it, but since it's the OS itself that's pirated, I wouldn't trust its results.

Comment: The problem is that I get a message from Microsoft Auto Recovery telling me that my key is not recognized. however my key is valid and genuine.

Comment: You should then contact Microsoft Support. After all you paid for Windows, so you're entitled to get help from them.